# Insert data from checkbox array into MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have some array or checkboxes and the checked values need to write to mysql tables. As of now its not writing to the db. So i doubt if iam doing the right way. The code below comes from an array of records from the db. Now its having 2 rows of checkboxes. It can one or two or three depending on the data.

My html is below:

```
<form action="comparitive_state_comprehensive_update.php?tender_id=1063" method="POST"></form>



                            <table class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" width="160">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30" width="170">Export Charges:</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">IATA Charges:</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">COC Charges:</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Calibration Charges:</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Third Party Insp. Chrg</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Ultrasonic Insp. Chrg</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Optional Access Cost</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Extended Warranty Chrg</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Installation &amp; Training</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Approx. Freight</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">Other Charges</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                           <table class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30" width="540">12&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="exportinr" value="12" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">34&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="iatainr" value="34" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">78&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="cocinr" value="7848.0783407565" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">54&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="calibrationinr" value="5433.2850051391" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">98&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="tpinr" value="9860.4061204376" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">32&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="ultrasoninr" value="3219.7244474898" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">19&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="optinr" value="1911.7113906971" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">25&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="extinr" value="2515.4097246014" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">67&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="instinr" value="6741.2980619318" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">16&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="freightinr" value="1609.8622237449" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">39&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="otherinr" value="3924.0391703782" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>


                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <table class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30" width="540">98&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="exportinr" value="8768.88" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">23&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="iatainr" value="4565.98" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">89&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="cocinr" value="76576.098" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">21&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="calibrationinr" value="87687.090" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">90&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="tpinr" value="24565.989" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">28&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="ultrasoninr" value="223.090" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">42&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="optinr" value="5465.09" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">65&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="extinr" value="1213.89" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">12&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="instinr" value="87678.88" type="checkbox"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30">19&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="freightinr" value="76576.98" type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="30">10&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[]" id="otherinr" value="78687687" type="checkbox"></td>
         </tr>

        </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Items to Quotation'>
            </form>
        </div>
```

My PHP script is below which inserts data:

```
$chkbox = $_POST['chk'];

$exportinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'exportinr');
$iatainr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'iatainr');
$cocinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cocinr');
$calibrationinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'calibrationinr');
$tpinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tpinr');
$ultrasoninr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ultrasoninr');
$optinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'optinr');
$extinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'extinr');
$instinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'instinr');
$freightinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'freightinr');
$otherinr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'otherinr');

$currency2 = $_POST['currency2'];


 $i = 0;
 While($i<sizeof($chkbox))
 {
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO quotation_terms (tender_id, export_charges_inr, iata_charges_inr, coc_charges_inr, calibration_charges_inr, tp_inspe_charges_inr, ultrason_inspe_charges_inr, opt_access_cost_inr, ext_warranty_cost_inr, inst_training_cost_inr, approx_freight_inr, other_charges_inr, currency1)

VALUES ('$tender_id','$exportinr','$iatainr','$cocinr','$calibrationinr','$tpinr','$ultrasoninr', '$optinr', '$extinr', '$instinr', '$freightinr', '$otherinr', '$currency2')");

 $i++;
 }
 echo "Checkbox value is successfully submitted.";
```

This is the actual PHP Form script:

```
    while($list1=mysql_fetch_array($add1))
    {
   echo '<tr><input type="checkbox" name="chk[exportinr]" id="exportinr" value='.$list1['export_charges'].'></td></tr>';
   echo '<tr><td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[iatainr]" id="iatainr" value='.$list1['iata_charges'].'></td></tr>';
          echo '<tr><td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[cocinr]" id="cocinr" value='.$list1['coc_charges_inr'].'></td></tr> ';
          echo '<tr><input type="checkbox" name="chk[calibrationinr]" id="calibrationinr" value='.$list1['calibration_charges_inr'].'></td></tr>';
          echo '<tr><input type="checkbox" name="chk[tpinr]" id="tpinr" value='.$list1['tp_inspe_charges_inr'].'></td></tr>';
              echo '<tr><input type="checkbox" name="chk[ultrasoninr]" id="ultrasoninr" value='.$list1['ultrason_inspe_charges_inr'].'></td></tr>';
          echo '<tr><td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[optinr]" id="optinr" value='.$list1['opt_access_cost_inr'].'></td></tr>';
          echo '<tr><td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[extinr]" id="extinr" value='.$list1['ext_warranty_cost_inr'].'></td></tr>';
          echo '<tr><td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[instinr]" id="instinr" value='.$list1['inst_training_cost_inr'].'></td></tr>';
          echo '<tr><td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="chkfreightinr[]" id="freightinr" value='.$list1['approx_freight_inr'].'></td></tr>';
          echo '<tr><td height="30"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[otherinr]" id="otherinr" value='.$list1['other_charges_inr'].'></td></tr>';
    }
```

Comment: You need to gather post data from the `name` attribute, not the `id`s of the checkboxes. PHP doesn't see the `id`, only the `name` and `value` attributes.

Comment: If you want to get exact name values you could have the `chk[]` contain array keys like `name="chk[otherinr]"`

Comment: And how will be the while loop for this to insert to mysql db?

Comment: You could do a `foreach()` on the `$_POST['chk']` if not empty.

Comment: Iam little confused, still let me try.

Comment: Also, the `while()` is kind of strange. Are you trying to add multiple rows in your database or just one row with all the column values??

Comment: Just one row, with all the checked values to the appropriate fields

Comment: Oh scratch that, I see what you are trying to do. You would probably need a multi-layered array

Comment: This example has two rows with mulitple checkboxes per row correct?

Comment: i have passed values for normal arrays and it worked fine. Iam having problem just because of multi-layered array.

Comment: yes, its could be one row or two rows or three rows depending on the data.

Comment: Yes this example has two rows.

Comment: Yeah, then you need to change your form to accommodate that.

Comment: Can i put the actual php form file, so that you can have a look?

Comment: I will write an answer for you. Give me a moment.

Comment: Thank you. Even i have edited the question and put the actual PHP form script also.

Comment: Sorry yeah, I am busy right now. Give me a few mins

Comment: sure, take your time...But pls dont forget :)

Answer (score 0):

You will get all the checked check boxes values inside `$_POST['chk']`

```
$checkedArr = $_POST['chk'];
```

Comment: After that a while loop and insert the data?

Comment: Hope you should use different names for different checkboxes since you want to take it separately in server side. Here you will get only one array contains all checked boxes values, can't identify which element is been checked.

Comment: After giving different names to different checkboxes. How will i capture the data in a for loop and insert in mysql db?

Comment: You have to take separately. so no need of loop.

Comment: i just tried to implement the same. Iam getting an error "Notice: Array to string conversion" on the insert statement. mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO quotation_terms (export_charges,...) VALUES ('$export_charges',..)

Comment: Just takes the first element of post elements which will be an array instead of taking the same and apply in query.

Answer (score 0):

You get array after submitting checkbox value. And you need to implode or parse that value and store in database.

```
 $checkedArr = $_POST['chk'];     //return an array.
 $checkboxvalue = implode(",", $checkedArr);
```

Then insert `$checkboxvalue` in to the mysql database. And you will get value in comma separated form. Then while fetching from database you can explode the db value and use `foreach` to show the values of checkbox.

Comment: Can u share more light on how to give the for or while loop to insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize your form like so (notice the `$i` incrementing and placement of the key):

```
<form action="comparitive_state_comprehensive_update.php?tender_id=1063" method="POST">
<table class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" width="160">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="170">Export Charges:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">IATA Charges:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">COC Charges:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Calibration Charges:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Third Party Insp. Chrg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Ultrasonic Insp. Chrg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Optional Access Cost</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Extended Warranty Chrg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Installation &amp; Training</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Approx. Freight</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30">Other Charges</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
    $data[] =   array(
                        "exportinr" =>  12,
                        "iatainr"   =>  34,
                        "cocinr"    =>  7848.0783407565,
                        "calibrationinr"    =>  5433.2850051391,
                        "tpinr" =>  9860.4061204376,
                        "ultrasoninr"   =>  3219.7244474898,
                        "optinr"    =>  1911.7113906971,
                        "extinr"    =>  2515.4097246014,
                        "instinr"   =>  6741.2980619318,
                        "freightinr"    =>  1609.8622237449,
                        "otherinr"  =>  3924.0391703782
                    );
    $data[] =   array(
                        "exportinr" =>  54,
                        "iatainr"   =>  23,
                        "cocinr"    =>  234.0783407565,
                        "calibrationinr"    =>  3453.2850051391,
                        "tpinr" =>  11111.4061204376,
                        "ultrasoninr"   =>  32132.7244474898,
                        "optinr"    =>  4433.7113906971,
                        "extinr"    =>  5224.4097246014,
                        "instinr"   =>  6666.2980619318,
                        "freightinr"    =>  231343.8622237449,
                        "otherinr"  =>  10303.0391703782
                    );

    $i = 0;             
    foreach($data as $row) {
?>
<table class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100">
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        foreach($row as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="540"><?php echo number_format($value,0); ?>&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo $key; ?>]" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php   $i++; 
    } ?>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Items to Quotation' />
</form>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:**

This should be the equivalent of the above code based on yours for the form. Note, you have `mysql_` where it should be `mysqli_`:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;             
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($add1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>
<table class="inlineTable" style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100">
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        foreach($row as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" width="540"><?php echo number_format($value,0); ?>&nbsp;GBP&nbsp;<input name="chk[<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo $key; ?>]" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php   $i++; 
    } ?>
```

---

Submitting this will give you an easily grouped array for processing:

```
Array
(
    [chk] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cocinr] => 7848.0783407565
                    [tpinr] => 9860.4061204376
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [iatainr] => 23
                    [calibrationinr] => 3453.2850051391
                )

        )

    [submit] => Add Items to Quotation
)
```

Processing the mysql into a query would be something like this *(there are lots of ways to process this with validation, this is pretty much send to DB with minimal validation)*:

```
if(!empty($_POST['chk'])) {
        // Loop through each row
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['chk']); $i++) {
                // Get just the values
                $arrVals    =   array_values($_POST['chk'][$i]);
                // Run through the values and sanitize for numeric/decimals/commas
                $arrVals    =   array_map(function($v) { $v = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.\,]/',"",$v); return $v; },$arrVals);
                // Implode the columns
                $setCols    =   "(`".implode("`,`",array_keys($_POST['chk'][$i]))."`)";
                // Implode the values
                $setVals    =   "('".implode("','",$arrVals)."')";
                // Save to database
                mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO quotation_terms {$setCols} values {$setVals}");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Iam a novice and really finding it difficult to understand this code and implementing it in my existing code. Still iam trying to achieve this

Comment: This line $data[] =   array(             "exportinr" =>  12, etc . How will i code in real php? Is this correct? <input type="checkbox" name="chk_export[]" id="exportinr" value='.$list1['export_charges'].'>

Comment: When I am in front of my computer again I will try and incorporate what you have. The `$data` in mine is a representation of the fetched data (`$list1`) from yours. One thing I just noticed is that you are using both `mysql_` and `mysqli_` which is incorrect.